# NAudio, is TwoTone supported?

Tags: naudio

I inherited this project that used `NAudio 1.7.1.16`.

In there they use `SignalGenerator.Frequency1` and `SignalGenerator.Frequency2` to generate a `TwoTone sound`.

However, the later version 1.7.2 and latest 1.7.3, Frequency1 and Frequency2 and SignalGeneratorType.TwoTone does not exist any more!

So how do I do the TwoTone thing with the latest version of NAudio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have inherited a custom build of NAudio. NAudio's `SignalGenerator` has never had a `TwoTone` option. It has been unchanged ever since [it was added in 2012](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/commit/37db57761378e99089d7b1396b2aa7d416d811e0).